# If we take STFT of a single sinusoid, and plot the value corresponding to carrier frequency in real imaginary plane, how many points should it be?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, trigonometry

I created a sinusoid with frequency 550Hz that goes for 1 second

```
fs=44100;
Duration=1;  %second
Len=Duration * fs;  %length of sinusoid
t=(0:Len-1)/fs;
x=sin(2*pi*550*t);
```

for the purpose of exploring and learning, I have decided to take the short time Fourier transform of this signal. I did it as below:

```
window_len=0.02*fs;  %length of the window
hop=window_len/3;    %hop size
nfft=2^nextpow2(window_len);
window=hamming(window_len,'periodic');
[S,f,t]=spectrogram(x,window,hop,nfft,fs);
```

Now I want to plot the real versus imaginary value of `S` for the frequency equal to 550 and see what happens. First of all, in the frequency vector I didn’t have the exact 550. There was one 516.5 and 559.6. So, I just looked at the spectrogram and chose whichever that was close to it and picked that. When I tried to plot real vs imaginary of `S` for the frequency I chose (over all time frames), the values all fall in 3 points as it shows in the attached plot. Why three points?

[image: The figure that shows value of STFT, corresponding to (almost) carrier frequency.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phase of the STFT coefficients for the different windows depends on which data exactly the window "sees". So for your particular choice of window length and hop, it so happens that as you slide through your single-frequency sinusoid, there only three different data chunks that you window "sees". To see what I mean, just plot:

`plot(x(1:window_len),'x')`

`plot(x(1+hop:window_len+hop),'x')`

`plot(x(1+2*hop:window_len+2*hop),'x')`

`plot(x(1+3*hop:window_len+3*hop),'x')`

.. and if you continue you will see that the pattern repeats itself, i.e., the first plot for instance is the same as the fourth, the second as the fifth etc. Therefore you only have three different real-imaginary part combinations.

Of course, this will change if you change the window length and the hopsize, and you will get more points. For instance, try

`window_len =nfft;`

`hop=ceil(window_len/4)`

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Each STFT window can have a different complex phase depending on how the start (or middle) of the window is synchronized (or not) with the sinusoids period.  So the real-complex IQ plot for the peak magnitude DFT result bin can be a circular scatter plot, depending on the number of DFT windows and the ratio between the stepping distance (or length - overlap) and the period of the sinusoid.